# Push notifications to angular web application

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, google-cloud-messaging

I have a mobile web application that is developed in angular and is running in a browser. I want to push notifications to it from the server.

The notifications should reach the client-side web application at least when it is open in the browser.
It will be a good-to-have to show notifications in the phone's notifications area if the application is not open in the browser. On clicking on the notification, I would then want to open the browser and take the user to the right page where the notifications are displayed inside the browser.

Kindly guide me on the technologies to be used. Should I use socket.io, GCM or any other tool.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Push notification is a service that need to be Incorporated with the server side of your application..

Considering, you are using Web Api framework, these steps could guide you well:

1. You would need a database table for `PushMessage` with a mandatory column as `IsActive` to need to know which messages are active.

   Another table in the DB would be to store all tokens which a device has.
2. You could create your own or use the available paid/free push notification services in the market. One example could be : [http://www.pushkonnect.com](http://www.pushkonnect.com/)
3. Next would be to create an `Azure hosted` or `.Net web job` which would queue up all the messages from the `PushMessage` table based on the `IsActive` flag is true.

Then the service picks up the message from the table, and shoots it to the mobile device based on the token of the device.

Comment: I meant, which technology do I need to use on the client side. This is a browser application. It is clear that notifications are initiated on the server side. But to push the notifications, should I use socket.io or google cloud messaging?